# XSD keyref contraints on multiple instances of same element

Tags: xml, validation, xpath, xsd

schema sample -

```
<xs:complexType name="EndPointType">
    <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:element name="Name" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
        <xs:element name="Pass" type="SIPMethodType" minOccurs="0" />
        <!-- other elements -->
        <xs:choice>
            <xs:element name="Method" type="MethodType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <xs:element name="MethodName" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
        </xs:choice>
    </xs:choice>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="MethodType">
    <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:element name="Name" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
        <xs:element name="Method" type="SIPMethodType" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
        <xs:element name="Response" type="SIPResponseCode" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
        <xs:element name="Direction" type="DirectionType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="4"/>
    </xs:choice>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:element name="SSME">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" >
                <xs:element name="Endpoint" type="EndPointType" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
                <xs:element name="Method" type="MethodType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
            </xs:choice>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:key name="MethodNameKey">
        <xs:selector xpath="./Method"/>
        <xs:field xpath="Name"/>
    </xs:key>
    <xs:keyref name="EpMethodKeyRef"  refer="MethodNameKey">
        <!-- endpoint->methodName (if present) must point at an existing method->name -->
        <xs:selector xpath="./Endpoint"/>
        <xs:field xpath="MethodName"/>
    </xs:keyref>
</xs:element>
```

xml with problems -

```
<Endpoint>
    <Name>ep1</Name>
    <MethodName>method1</MethodName>
    <MethodName>method2</MethodName>
</Endpoint> 

<Method>
    <Name>method1</Name>
    <Method>CANCEL</Method>
    <Direction>Outbound</Direction>
</Method>   

<Method>
    <Name>method2</Name>
    <Method>INVITE</Method>
    <Direction>Inbound</Direction>
</Method>
```

xmllint gives me - 
 element MethodName: Schemas validity error : Element 'MethodName': The XPath 'MethodName' of a field of keyref identity-constraint 'EpMethodKeyRef' evaluates to a node-set with more than one member.

How do I specify EpMethodKeyRef keyref to allow 0-n instances of MethodName, each which must contain a Method that has already been defined in MethodNameKey?
I have tried

```
<xs:field xpath="MethodName[0]"/>
<xs:field xpath="MethodName[1]"/>
<xs:field xpath="MethodName[*]"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The xs:selector must select each element having a foreign key reference, while the xs:field points to that reference for each element.

MethodName should be moved over to xs:selector, and xs:field should have the context item . instead. That way, each element MethodName will get atomized to take its value and compare it with the key, just like the element Name is atomized in the key declaration.

```
    <xs:keyref name="EpMethodKeyRef"  refer="MethodNameKey">
        <!-- endpoint->methodName (if present) must point at an existing method->name -->
        <xs:selector xpath="./Endpoint/MethodName"/>
        <xs:field xpath="."/>
    </xs:keyref>
```

Multiple use of the xs:field with the same selector has a different semantics which create tuple keys.